# How can i get md5 from resized file before saving it to new file?

Tags: php, resize, md5

I'm doing resize on jpg, after that i would like to get md5 from it and then save new image with that MD5 name.
Code looks like that:

```
$extension = 'jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $plik[0], $plik[1]);

//$md5 - here i need to get md5...

imagejpeg($tmp_img, $md5.;'.'.$extension);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Is it possible without saving that tmp file first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do at the top...

```
$md5 = md5_file($source);
```

I've also seen a technique where you stream the image file into an output buffer and capture that.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($tmp_img);
$data = ob_get_clean();

$md5 = md5($data);
```

You could then create your file with...

```
file_put_contents($md5 . '.' . $extension, $data);
```

Comment: @alex ob_end_clean() discards the contents of the buffer, you need to use ob_get_clean() to actually get the data. Then your solution is valid but with an extra call to imagejpeg which might be costly for very large images.

Comment: @Yannis Whoops, I always forget what `ob_*()` function I want. Thanks :)

Comment: @Yannis Rizos, no need in extra call - $data can be flushed to the file.

Comment: @OZ Right you are! Didn't think about that, but yes you already have the data why get it again...

Comment: @Yannis Rizos thanks, you are right, with ob_get_clean() it works

Comment: @baranq Nice. But I just did a small correction, you should mark alex's answer as the accepted one.